# angularJs ng-disabled not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
{
    $scope.editable = true;
    $scope.NewEmployee = function () {
        $scope.editable = false;
    };

    $scope.EditEmployee = function () {
        $scope.editable = false;
        $scope.Employee.edit = true;
    };

    $scope.Cancel = function () {
        $scope.editable = true;
    };
}

<button ng-click="NewEmployee()"></button>
<button ng-click="EditEmployee()" ></button>
<button ng-click="Save()" ng-disabled="editable"></button>
<button ng-class="Cancel()" ng-disabled="editable"></button>
```

when there is only NewEmployee() it's work

but I add  EditEmployee() Save() Cancel() one of these it's not work

Answer (score 2):

There is a TYPO error in your code

`<button ng-class="Cancel()" ng-disabled="editable"></button>`

`ng-class="Cancel()"`  this should be like `ng-click="Cancel()"`

Comment: Perhaps this is just a typo in question itself only. Because OP has mentioned its not working on EditEmployee, Save also...

Comment: Oh,Thank you  I didnt see that.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: `ng-disabled` was not working because the typo `ng-class` directive was not executed as it was disabled by default & `ng-disabled` has highest priority compared to `ng-class`, but once enabled it failed to process `ng-class` as it was not in a right format.